# local variable 'count' referenced before assignment when trying to count behind a tkinter frame

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have made a simple `tkinter` script to throw up a window and count up in the back ground (in the terminal). However every time I try to write the counting function, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Sandip Dhillon/Desktop/stuff/dev_tests/test1.py", line 35, in <module>
    Printer.add_count()
  File "c:/Users/Sandip Dhillon/Desktop/stuff/dev_tests/test1.py", line 31, in add_count
    count += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong I just can't seem to figure out what.

Here is my code;

```py
import tkinter as tk


# --- Main application set up ---
main_app = tk.Tk()
main_app.title('DT1')
#width_value=main_app.winfo_screenwidth()
#height_value=main_app.winfo_screenheight()

width_value=1200
height_value=800

main_app.geometry("%dx%d-0-0" % (width_value, height_value))

# Frame setup
frame = tk.Frame(main_app, bg='#000000')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# DES Logo
DES_logo=tk.Label(frame, text='DT1', font='ariel 18 bold', bg='#000000', fg='#626262')
DES_logo.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.91, relwidth=0.20, relheight=0.05)

# Counter
count = 0 

class Printer():
    
    @staticmethod
    def add_count():
        count += 1
        print(count)
        main_app.after(500,Printer)

Printer.add_count()

main_app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `global count` just at the start of your `add_count` function

Comment: @TheLizzard as op is already working with classes, a static class variable would be better than a `global`

Comment: @user_na I don't know if OP will have multiple instances of `Printer` and if all of them are supposed to have their own `count` variable. Or maybe OP wants to have only 1 count variable. Given that OP knows about `@staticmethod` I assume that if OP wanted they would have put `count` inside the class

Comment: @TheLizzard  using the global variable worked! thanks

Comment: @user_na I tried to put count inside the class I got the same error :/ , how would you do it in this scenario?

Comment: @SandipDhillon see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Static Variable

```
# Counter

class Printer():
    count = 0
    @staticmethod
    def add_count():
        Printer.count += 1
        print(Printer.count)
        main_app.after(500,Printer.add_count)

Printer.add_count()

main_app.mainloop()
```

Using a Global Variable

```
# Counter
count = 0 

class Printer():
    
    @staticmethod
    def add_count():
        global count
        count += 1
        print(count)
        main_app.after(500,Printer.add_count)

Printer.add_count()

main_app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make the `count`variable a static class variable of `Printer`. This has fewer risks of uninteded changes of the variable.

```
class Printer():
    count = 0
    @staticmethod
    def add_count():
        Printer.count += 1
        print(count)
        main_app.after(500,Printer)

Printer.add_count()
```

Be aware that you can only access the static variable via the Class not via an instance:

```
>>> p = Printer()
>>> p.count = 5
>>> p.count
5
>>> Printer.count
1
>>> Printer.count = 7
>>> Printer.count
7
>>> p.count
5
```